# access large number of filenames

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I have 100 directories and within each directory contains 1 file which I need to access together all 100 files like

```
hadd 1/result1.root 2/result2.root ........100/result100.root.
```

I can print out the name (I have done as shown below) but how to use those names all together?

```
#!/bin/bash

for dset in {1..101}
do
    #echo $dset/results$dset.root
    ls -l $dset/*.root | awk '{printf("%s", $9)}'
done
```

How do I call the filenames since I dont save anything in array?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 {1..101}/*.root | xargs echo hadd
```

Remove the `echo` part when you're satisfied with the output.